# VBA code: Count Cells with same value then add formula to Chart

Tags: vba, charts, count

I am trying to count the number of cells in a column with similar values. Then that count result will be multiplied to 5. The final result will then be created to a bard chart.

I have looked several macro and tried to record the process i am doing (using pivot table) but still can't get any luck. I am not really well versed with coding but appreciate any help from you. Thanks!

I had create a code as below by modifying macro i searched from the net. However, it is counting even the rows that were hidden after filtering. ALso, I haven;t able to output it as chart.

Sample Table:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ8li.png)

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim mess As String
Dim rngcheck As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim E As Range
Dim objDic
Dim i As Variant
Dim pcs As Variant
Dim p As Variant
Dim u As Single

'Dim strMsg As String

Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set rng1 = Range([E1], Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
u = 0
For Each E In rng1
    If Len(E.Value) > 0 Then
        If Not objDic.exists(E.Value) Then
            objDic.Add E.Value, CStr(E.Address)
            'u = u + 1
        Else
            objDic(E.Value) = objDic(E.Value) & ", " & CStr(E.Address)
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim comma As String, strMsg As String
'
strMsg = ""
For Each i In objDic.Keys
    pcs = Split(objDic(i), ",")
    If UBound(pcs) > 1 Then
        u = (UBound(pcs) + 1) * 5 / 60
'        MsgBox i & " = " & UBound(pcs) + 1 & " hrs: " & u
        strMsg = strMsg & i & " = " & UBound(pcs) + 1 & " hrs: " & u
        comma = ""
        For Each p In pcs
                strMsg = strMsg & comma '& p
                'comma = ", "
        Next

        strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine
    End If

Next
'
If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then MsgBox strMsg
```

Now, I am having problem with SOrting only a specific cells.

```
With Sheets("DT_Status" & u)
    .Select
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Sheets("DT_Status" & u).Range(Cells(StartFilt, 1), Cells(EndFilt, 3)), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    '.Sort.SetRange Sheets("DT_Status" & u).Range(Cells(StartFilt, 1), Cells(EndFilt, 3))
    .Sort.Apply
    .Shapes.AddChart.Select
    '.ChartObject.Name = "Chart_" & Sheets("Summary").Range("H" & x).Value
End With
```

Getting error '1004': “The sort reference is not valid.”

Comment: You can do this with a pivot table. Create a pivot table, make your field a row field and then group it.

Comment: Hi Sam. I need it to be on a VBA. since the source data changes. Thus, need it to be in code.

Comment: worksheet function [SubTotal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.subtotal?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137240)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) will account for filtered cells, use 2 (Count) for Arg1

Comment: Thanks. Though I resolved it using special cells. 
rng1 = Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)